# How to remove points after characters in a specific column pandas

Tags: pandas, character, point

I loaded a large dataframe and I have a column with Ensembl values ex: ENGS00000000.1,ENGS003490.12 and etc. I am trying to remove the point and the values after the points. The DF itself has numeric values and contain float characters which mustn't removed.

```
  df = pd.read_csv("Fileinfo1.csv")
df["Ensembl_ID"] = pd.set_option('precision', 1)
df.head()
```

If I did correctly, this is the code (not sure why but it doesn't print..) is there any option to remove them all from the column instead of changing the set_option everytime?

Comment: If you're executing a python script you might want to do `print(df.head())` to print. `df["Ensembl_ID"] = df['Ensembl_ID'].str.split('.').str[0]` should give you only the part of the string before the dot

Comment: Oh.. made a really silly mistake .. thank you very much for answering!